# How to search for all possible combinations of adding a letter to a word?

Tags: c++, binary-search

I have been stuck on this problem forever. What I'm trying to do is to see how many possible ways I can add a letter to a word using some sort of binary search methodology.

For example suppose I have the a word that is 4 letters long, then the word is: `----`

Now suppose I want to see all possible ways that I could add an "Y" to this word. All possible combinations would then be 2^4 and it would look like:

```
----    
---Y
--Y-
--YY
-Y--
-Y-Y
-YY-
-YYY
Y---
Y--Y
Y-Y-
Y-YY
YY--
YY-Y
YYY-
YYYY
```

How can I get all of these combinations? I'm then planning to add all of these combinations to a list of strings that I then will use to compare to a set of words.

Comment: The term you're looking for is not "binary search", but *permutations*.

Comment: you add one y or many ?

Comment: It could be both one y or many. It's all possible ways to add y to the word. @firsni

Comment: I posted my idea on how to tackle the problem @yellow shirt

Answer (score 3):

you can see it as binary problem. It's all the numbers from 0000 to 1111 in binary base. And then you map 1 to Y

Answer (score 0):

Why not a recursive complete search? Something like the following should work:
It works like this:
If you want to generate all possible string of length `n` you could either insert either a `'Y'` or a `'-'` in the first position. 
Once you made your decision you can append your choice to all possible combinations of  length `n-1`.

Here is it a possible implementation that you can try [online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/H0DwdUCa9p96m6ZD):

```
vector<string>  generate_p(const int n){
    vector<string> ans;
    if(n==0)
    {
        ans.push_back("");   
    }
    else
    {
        auto v = generate_p(n-1);    
        for(size_t i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; i++){
            ans.push_back("Y"+v[i]);
            ans.push_back("-"+v[i]);
        }
    }
    return ans;   
}
```

---

Another approach would be to notice that for each position you have two choice: 'Y' or '-' like you have for a binary number where you can choose between '1' or '0'. 
So, if you list all numbers from `'0000'` to `'1111'` in base `'2'` you get all your combos. I leave that as an exercise to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the algo [next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "____";
    std::string per;
    int count = 1;
    // first combi 
    std::cout << s << '\n';
    for (auto i=0;i<s.size();i++)
    {
    //character for replacement 
    s[i] = 'y';
    per = s;
    std::sort(per.begin(), per.end());
    do {
        std::cout << per << '\n';
        count++;
    } while(std::next_permutation(per.begin(), per.end()));
    }
     std::cout << "Number of Combination is "  << count<<'\n';
}
```

Output

```
____
___y
__y_
_y__
y___
__yy
_y_y
_yy_
y__y
y_y_
yy__
_yyy
y_yy
yy_y
yyy_
yyyy
Number of Combination is 16
```